# What's the reason for "fork: Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: ant, cron, fedora

I'm running a bunch of cronjobs on a fedora server 24 hours.

However, sometimes in a day, the cronjobs fail because of

```
fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

This situation would last for about 1 or 2 hours, and then stop.

The time it happens might be different everyday.

I'm using fedora release 10. The jobs I'm running are a bunch of shell scripts, each corresponding to one or more ant tasks.

Comment: As an aside, unless you're running this in a completely isolated machine, I'd not advise running Fedora 10. The oldest supported release is Fedora 20 now.

Answer (score 2):

It may cause because of exceeding the maximum number of open files in your system.Try again after increasing the max LSOF limit.